# JavaScript not updating the DOM and crashing the browser

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-chrome

I have written the following HTML for a button that on click calls a function and the output of the function is written in a div in the DOM. But it is not updating the DOM anyway, but freezing the whole browser tab as well as the HTML page. Please help.

Thank you in advance

```
let rows = [];
let cols = [];
let secKey = "";
const generateKey = () => {
  var count = 0;
  while (count != 5) {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
    if (!rows.includes(randomNumber)) {
      rows.push(randomNumber);
      count++;
    }
  }
  count = 0;
  while (count != 6) {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
    if (!cols.includes(randomNumber)) {
      cols.push(randomNumber);
      count++;
    }
  }
  // put on the document
  secKey = `${cols[0]}${rows[0]}${cols[1]}${rows[1]}${cols[2]}${rows[2]}${cols[3]}${rows[3]}${cols[4]}${rows[4]}${cols[5]}`;
  document.querySelector("#sec-key").innerHTML = `Your secret key is <strong id="sec-key">${secKey}</strong>`; // #sec-key is a div where I want to show the output
};
```

Html:

```
<div class="key-container">
  <button id="generate-key" class="util-btn" onclick="generateKey()">Generate new secret key</button>
  <p class="key-holder" id="sec-key">
    <!--output is expected here-->
  </p>
  <p id="caution">*please remember the secret key for decryption</p>
</div>
```

Comment: WARNING: Goes without saying, but running the code snippet and clicking the button can crash your browser.

Comment: Edited to *not* be a snippet

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that upon running the function a second time, the globals likely already include the random values, and so the `count` variable is never incremented and the loop spins infinitely.

Either initialize the globals inside the function implementation, or use the length of the array instead of a counter. Second approach is shown below:

```
let rows = [];
let cols = [];
let secKey = "";
const generateKey = () => {

  while (rows.length != 5) {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
    if (!rows.includes(randomNumber)) {
      rows.push(randomNumber);
    }
  }

  while (cols.length != 6) {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
    if (!cols.includes(randomNumber)) {
      cols.push(randomNumber);
    }
  }
  // put on the document
  secKey = `${cols[0]}${rows[0]}${cols[1]}${rows[1]}${cols[2]}${rows[2]}${cols[3]}${rows[3]}${cols[4]}${rows[4]}${cols[5]}`;
  document.querySelector("#sec-key").innerHTML = `Your secret key is <strong id="sec-key">${secKey}</strong>`; // #sec-key is a div where I want to show the output
};
```

Comment: I have changed the arrays from global initialization to local, and the infinite loop error is resolved, but still, the DOM can't be modified.